# How to update fragment content from activity (viewpager)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a simple viewPager with two fragments. Each fragment contains a TextView. I would like to be able to update the text of the current textView displayed from the activity.

**Activity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Live.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Hit.class.getName()));

        this.pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Adapter :**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

**Fragment :**

```
public class Live extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.live, container,false);
    }
}
```

**XML Fragment :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:text="First Fragment"
              android:id="@+id/status"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each fragment have a TextView with the id "status".
Updating the text view in `onCreateView` works. But how can i update the textView from anywhere in the activity ?

I have tried this without succes :

**Fragment :**

```
public class Live extends Fragment {    
    public TextView tv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live, container,false);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Activity :**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Live frag = (Live) pagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        frag.tv.setText("Test 2");
    }
```

But it gives me a nullPointerException on `tv`, probably because the fragment is not yet inflated.

I already read the following questions without success :

- [Updating fragments from Activity in a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341591/updating-fragments-from-activity-in-a-viewpager)
- [Update a TextView in a ViewPager from another Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151811/update-a-textview-in-a-viewpager-from-another-fragment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `MyPagerAdapter` class, Android calls `getItem(...)` only if it wants to create new Fragments. So it's problematic to use references there instead you should instatiate the fragments.

Check this Answer [support-fragmentpageradapter-holds-reference-to-old-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9745935/1108036)

Comment: This is 100% right. I have already made this same mistake as the OP. Do NOT keep your own array of `Fragment`s. The `FragmentManager` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter` holds all of `Fragment`s and manages saving and restoring their state. They can be referenced as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-viewpager/14530629#14530629.

Comment: Ok did it using : http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html and second solution of http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html . But from what i have experienced it's not possible to access the fragment in on create or on resume in the activity right ?

Comment: It's probably not awailable/inflated at that time. Why don't you use the fragments own lifecycle?

Comment: As long as the `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` are created/connected, the `Fragment`s should be created/resumed. I have been able to access them in both methods, I just always check if my `fragment.isResumed()` before trying to do anything with it. Honestly, the answer in the link I posted is much more elegant, as you can get your `Fragment`s right out of the `FragmentManager`, no need to keep track yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue like this, create the adapter like this

```
package com.yubraj.sample.adapter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.yubaraj.sample.activities.RashiFragment;
import java.util.List;


public class PageSliderAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    static String[] titleList = new String[] { "today",
            "this month", "this year" };
    List<String> rashi;
    // private static String TAG = "pagerscreenslider";

    public PageSliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> rashiList) {
        super(fm);
        this.rashi = rashiList;
    }
    public void updateData(List<String> rashisList){
        rashi.clear();
        this.rashi = rashisList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new RashiFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("RASHI", rashi.get(position));
        bundle.putInt("RASHI_TYPE", position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titleList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titleList[position];
    }


}
```

Then from Your activity

```
List<String> rashiCollection = getJSONFromDb(Dates);
adapter.updateData(rashiCollection);
```

Comment: i have been trying this for quite some time now but whenever i call notifydatasetchanged it in turn calls the addOnTabSelectedListener which results in an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    XXXFragment fragment = (XXXFragment) object;
        if(…condition){
    fragment.refresh(…);
    }
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
```

override the above. when you call notifyDataSetChanged(), the above method's triggered. do your refresh as you can.